# OSX Docker is nearly always consuming about 4GB of RAM with no active containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Like clockwork, basically every day my computer will start running slowly, and I discover `com.docker.hyperkit` is eating up about 4GB of RAM.

There are no active containers, I haven't used it in months and it's surely not updating or anything *every day*.

Is it supposed to be that hungry? If it's meant to consume that much RAM I'll just uninstall it.

Comment: Anyone reading in 2022, com.docker.hyperkit is still eating up the memory even when no containers up, and the only way was to disable kubernetes in docker preferences and reset k8s cluster.

Answer (score 4):

Docker runs natively only on Linux. On OSX there is a LinuxKit VM for Docker Desktop for Mac underneath to emulate Linux.
This of course adds some overhead. It's meant to be used for development and not for production.

[Here](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/178#issuecomment-238509543) is some explanation about the memory usage.

Comment: No no I totally understand that. I don't have a single app that launches on startup, stays idle, but eats 4GB of RAM at any given point. I was just trying to work out whether that's normal.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/178#issuecomment-238509543) is some explanation. Maybe that helps you.

Comment: Seems ok for docker for windows with hyper-v, if this confirm, then docker for mac really ...

Comment: Yes, I agree. Docker for Mac is kind of a mess. Especially the filesystem-performance in mounted volumes.

Comment: @vrdrv I suggest you need to update the link in comments to answer & also add some words in this link to answer as this is the really one which may answer OP's question.